# How to add space between a div and the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have this div that extends downwards beyond the page height and the white spacing under the div disappears, how do I add the white spacing back?

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 136px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

[Here's a picture of the bugged div being inspected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQN3J.png)

Comment: `div { bottom: value; }`  and an added overflow rule.

Comment: Um, thanks? Is this an answer or a comment? I think you should answer instead of commenting to get credit if this is an answer.

Comment: no because this is litterally a comment. Not sufficient enough for an answer content-wise. Not every solution here should be given as an answer and taken credit for.

Comment: Oh, it also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `margin-top` instead of `top`, that way that distance is *added* at the top instead of the `div` just being *moved* by that value, in relation to its original position in the document flow (which doesn't extend the height of the parent element).

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 136px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'bottom' & 'top' to position absoulte

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  position: absoulote;
 bottom: 100px;
top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum<br>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

When you move an element by adding a `top` value, you're doing just that - moving it down the page, without necessarily changing anything else. So, if you take an element that would have been positioned with white space around and add a `top` value, you will almost certainly move it down so that it now is over the space that would have been there. In this case, the element in your snippet looks to have been moved down so far that it's now against the bottom.

The problem I have in suggesting a solution is that I have absolutely no idea how your question relates to the screenshot you posted. That image shows a div occupying the full vertical height of the window and that doesn't appear to have `top` set at all! And, more than that, you're showing the `#Content` properties in a popup while having the `body` element selected in the Inspector panel to the right.

So, as an initial suggestion: add a spacer div at the bottom of your content div that puts a white block there.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 136px;
}

.spacer {
  background-color: white;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum1<br>Lorem Ipsum2<br>Lorem Ipsum3<br>Lorem Ipsum4<br>Lorem Ipsum5<br>Lorem Ipsum6<br>Lorem Ipsum7<br>Lorem Ipsum8<br>Lorem Ipsum9<br>Lorem Ipsum10<br>Lorem Ipsum11<br>Lorem Ipsum12<br>Lorem Ipsum13<br>Lorem Ipsum14</p>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why add a space div? IMHO very bad coding on all levels. Easier then adding a hardcoded spacer would be to use a pseudo-element: `div :last-child::after { content: ""; height: 60px; }`. However to achieve the same result just use `div { padding-bottom: 60px }`

Comment: That's a bit harsh, @tacoshy. Adding padding would not produce the same result at all - it would give more *grey* area, not white area. This may not be the most elegant solution but it works. An `::after` would be a good way to produce the same result.